# Sensor doesn't move from an initial pose for navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all.

I'm having some troubles trying to make a map. I'm driving the wheeled robot by teleop_twist_keyboard and it moves around, but the vision sensor (kinect) seems doesn't detect itself inside the map. It only actualizes what it sees in front of it, even if rotates. Here are the portions of map I got.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[http://imgur.com/a/FbGaj](https://imgur.com/a/FbGaj)

My tf tree
[image: image description]

And here the files I have for my project

https://github.com/gersonos/Yirsoon_environment_mapping

Which parameters should I change in order to make the sensor moves in combination with the robot? Maybe inside Rviz?

------------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------------------

On github I attached the files I'm using as `All files for navigation` and the `tf_tree I got`. Also I added some pictures of terminals used and fragments of the map I got. As you can see is set only looking in one direction, even if it moves and rotate.

What can be the problem I have on my files? I've tried to change lots of parameters that could affect it performance without sucess.

------------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE2--------------------------------------------------------------

On my github page I attached some pictures of `rostopic echo` values that it shows. Which are the following:

https://github.com/gersonos/Yirsoon_environment_mapping/tree/master/rostopics%20echo

```
rostopic echo /scan
rostopic echo /odom
rostopic echo /rpm
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
rostopic list -v
rqg_graph
```

As you can see, for /scan topic there are a lot of "nan" and numbers for rangers. There, only `ranges` seems change. Maybe `angle_min | angle_max` are the responsables of my issue.

For rostopic echo /odom, only changes `x position` and `x linear` for it covariance when it moves around. And it's only detecting forward movement because of my problem, so...it's OK.

For rostopic echo /rpm, the `z` vector is always on 0.1 but x vector increase when it's moving and it should be OK.

/cmd_vel also print the the suppostly given speed which is 0.04 [m/s] and a turn of 0.1[rad/s] when changes it directions, so no problem.

For rostopic list I attached only the suscribed topics used for you can see, and as a complement of that the rqt_graph.

[http://imgur.com/a/nF2Xe](https://imgur.com/a/nF2Xe)   (Rqt_graph I have)
[image: image description]

------------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE3--------------------------------------------------------------

After playing with the parameters I managed to solve my odometry problem. Now I'm able to generate a more accurate map. By the moment isn't good at all, but close to what it should be.

[image: my first map]

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269758/sensor-doesn%27t-move-from-an-initial-pose-for-navigation-stack/) by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Could you please post the images on an image hosting site such as imgur (unless you are given enough karma to post them here)? I'm a bit reluctant to download random files from the internet.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thanks, here are some pictures [http://imgur.com/a/FbGaj](https://imgur.com/a/FbGaj)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Also, please upload your code to a hosting site such as https://github.com (and possibly put relevant code here) because I have to download your code in order to read it (and like I said earlier I don't download random files from the internet).

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
How long were you mapping for? Sometimes it takes a bit for things to get settled and rviz to show you moving around your map.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
Here is the github link for the files I created. https://github.com/gersonos/Yirsoon_environment_mapping and thanks, is a great tool for sharing files for projects like this. I was mapping a while, but for now without sucess. Hope it helps to you to find what can be the problem.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
You know... maybe inside rviz for `LaserScan` I should modify other parameters like `Decay time`, `Size`, etc. There I only choose the `/scan` topic as well `/odom` and `/map` topics for those display options.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Decay time and size will only help with visualization in rviz.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
How are you running everything? Can you update your question with that and any relevant terminal output.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-29**:
I've attached on github all terminals displayed and what sees the kinect. I hope you can find what's going on in there. Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-30**:
@gerson_n: I've given you enough karma to be able to attach your images to your question directly. Could I ask you to do that? Thanks.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-30**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for the karma. I've uploaded the main pictures of my project. I hope it helps to you to understand what could be my problem in there.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-31**:
I've tried changing almost all parameters that could have change the kinect position. Maybe the problem is with odometry. But for rostopic echo rpm/cmd_vel positions seems change. How can I measure encoder's values?

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-31**:
I've noticed that even though the kinect doesn't move in complement with robot. After drive around a while, it moves only 1 or 2 meters.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-31**:
You know... I haven't seen other poeple have this kind of issues. It has to be something with the odometry received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your tf tree it looks like you are using `gmapping` for localization. You should use `amcl` for localization during navigation. `gmapping` is more suited to mapping (hence the word "mapping" in `gmapping`).

Checkout [`gmapping` on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) and [`amcl` on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
Yes, I'm using gmapping, but at the moment I try to generate the map, it only sees what is in front of it initial point of view. So, when I drive around it doesn't change it position, only the thing it sees in the first direction it saw the environment, as I showed in the first link.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Please post the images on an image hosting site such as imgur or don't gzip them. I don't download random files from the internet.

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-08-28**:
AMCL is for localization after mapping, or with an known map. That's the reason I didn't use AMCL for generate a map. BTW when I execute amcl it needs a map and I don't have it yet. Is there something I'm missing for make the kinect moves in combination with the wheeled robot I have? Thanks

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-28**:
Sorry, I misread your question. Yes, `amcl` is for navigating a known map and `gmapping` is for creating maps. If you're running both at the same time though, you may have issues.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-09-08**:
Maybe we should check if this is related to gmapping at all. What happens if you use "odom" as global frame?

**Comment by [gerson_n](https://answers.ros.org/users/29953/gerson_n/) on 2017-09-09**:
An hour ago, I solved the odometry problem. Now it's updating it position by receiving odometry information. The problem was a mistake I had for the `encoders supply`, and a wrong `theta` declaration on the base_controller.cpp file. So, it's solved.